# I have a question on SAML session management and Single Logout Option (SLO)

Tags: saml-2.0

I am new to SAML, and I have gone through the specs once.
My question is: if I logged on through two machines or two different browers (eg. Firefox and Chrome) on the same machine, does SAML create two sessions at the IdP (Identity Provider)?

If one of the applications at one of the SPs (Service Providers) initiates a SLO operation, does it logout only those connections to the other SPs from the same session?

My understanding is that the IdP creates two sessions so that if the SP initiates a logout, only those connections associated with the same browser (eg. Firefox) get logged off, the other connections from other browser sessions (eg. Chrome) or initiated from other machines are not affected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're interpretation is correct with how it works in a real world scenario.

It could be possible though that an Idp would implement some kind of cross-client session mechanism. I think that it would be permissible with the spec to do that. Technically it would be challenging as it would require back-channel logout messages (SOAP binding).